# Print first word based on 5 last words from a file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file with below content and I want to print the first word only if it is starting with `P` and if last 5 characters is `12`

File:

```
papa;1;2;3;4;5;12;12;12;12;12
Peter;12;12;12;12;12
alpha;2;2;2;4;5;6;7;8;9;3;3;3;3;3
Prod;1;2;3;4;1;1;1;1;12;12;12;12;12
```

Expected output:

```
Peter  
Prod
```

My attempt:

```
cat filename | awk -F '[;]' '{print substr( $0,length($0)-5,length($0))}' 
cat filename | egrep -V 'p|a' | awk -F '[;]' '{print $1}'
```

But I couldn't join the output.

---

Update:-

From the comments in the accepted answer, apparently OP says there could be lines less than 5 fields in the final file also.

Comment: _print the first character_ or word?

Comment: Sorry it's word..

Comment: Inian, I tried below 2 commands but couldn't join the output, I do not even consider myself as beginner in scripting. Hence the help.cat filename | awk -F '[;]' '{print substr( $0,length($0)-5,length($0))}'


cat filename | egrep -V 'p|a' | awk -F '[;]' '{print $1}'

Comment: _last 5 characters equals 12_ - what does it even mean?

Comment: @James, Updated.. If last 5 characters is '12'

Comment: Or if last 5 fields or columns are 12?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A crude way of doing it in `Awk` for the first word alone

```
awk -F';' '$1 ~ /^P/ && NF > 5 {c=0; for(i=NF-4;i<=NF;i++) {if($i==12){c++}} if(c==5) print $1} ' file
Peter
Prod
```

and if the whole line is needed remove `$1` in `print` statement

```
awk -F';' '$1 ~ /^P/ && NF > 5 {c=0; for(i=NF-4;i<=NF;i++) {if($i==12){c++}} if(c==5) print} ' file
Peter;12;12;12;12;12
Prod;1;2;3;4;1;1;1;1;12;12;12;12;12
```

How it works?

- The part `$1 ~ "^P"` is a regex match to filter out lines starting with `P`
- On the lines starting with above, parse last 5 fields (loop using `NF` and by maintaining a counter and print the line if 5 instances of `12` are found.

Comment: I am recieving the below error.  fatal: attempt to access field -1

Comment: @Sunny1985: I ran it on your sample input file and it worked. Is your input file same as the one in question

Comment: No it's not the same, It is a very big file in life , But in same format.

Comment: @Sunny1985: Then your logic is wrong, apparently there is a line starting with `P` and having _less than_ 5 fields in your big file. The error is trying to access a line having less than 5 fields.

Comment: Yes I see some entries with less than 5 fields. Can you make it to work..

Comment: @Sunny1985: Check the updated answer, added condition `NF > 5`

Comment: You should use `$1 ~ /^P/`, or even just `/^P/` since this is the start of the line. Also I'm not sure why you would use `-vFS=` instead of `-F`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another one with `awk`

```
$ cat ip.txt 
papa;1;2;3;4;5;12;12;12;12;12
Peter;12;12;12;12;12
alpha;2;2;2;4;5;6;7;8;9;3;3;3;3;3
Prod;1;2;3;4;1;1;1;1;12;12;12;12;12
Post;1;3;12;12;12

$ awk -F';' '/^P.*(;12){5}$/{print $1}' ip.txt 
Peter
Prod
```

- `/^P.*(;12){5}$/` line starting with `P` ending with `;12;12;12;12;12`

Comment: Nice answer `++`, call me old-fashioned but I'd take an answer with looping over the ever-confusing regex way ;)

Comment: yeah, regex takes lot of practice to get used to and easy to make mistakes ;)

Comment: Thanks for sharing Nice solution Sundeep.